# Unable to Get FriendList information using latest Facebook SDK3.0

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I'm a newbie to facebook sdk development on android and, I'm making a Graph API query to retrieve FriendList information from my facebook profile.

I'm using the latest sdk. There are solutions on `SOF w.r.t old sdk` but I want to implement it using the latest kit.

The query to `/me/friends` return a `JSON` response with the `name` and `IDs` of friends which I was easily able to parse. But when I tried to get extra information like birthdays by querying `/me/friends/?fields=birthday`, I'm getting an invalid response.

I have set the permissions for `friends_birthday` also in the `onCreateView` method below.

Here is my code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    authButton.setFragment(this);
    authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_location", "user_birthday", "user_likes","read_friendlists","friends_birthday"));   /*setting permissions*/
    userInfoTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userInfoTextView);
    return view;
}


public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null &&
           (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
    }
    uiHelper.onResume();
}


private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
        userInfoTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.REQUESTS);
        String graphpath="/me/friends?fields=name,birthday";

        Request.executeGraphPathRequestAsync(session, graphpath, new Request.Callback(){

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                try {
                        userInfoTextView.setText(buildUserInfoDisplay(response));
                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    Log.d(TAG,"JSON exception");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }



        });
    }


 else if (state.isClosed()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
        userInfoTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}



 private String buildUserInfoDisplay(Response response) throws JSONException  {

        if(response.getError()!=null)
        Log.d(TAG, "null reponse returned...");
    GraphObject go  = response.getGraphObject();
    JSONObject  jso = go.getInnerJSONObject();
        JSONArray   arr = jso.getJSONArray( "data" );
        JSONObject json_obj = arr.getJSONObject(2);   /*getting the third friend from the list*/
        String birthday   = json_obj.getString( "birthday"); 
        return birthday;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not all friends have birthday entries. So you will need to check if there is a 'birthday' tag available before reading it directly. You can test the result in Graph Explorer

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Ffriends%3Ffields%3Dname%2Cid%2Cbirthday

Comment: Yes I have already checked that. I am trying to query birthday information from that friend with birthday entry. Basically what i get is a null JSON response with neither the IDs, names or anything when i say "/me/friends/?fields=birthday". Atleast with "me/friends" I used to get the names and  the IDs. Anything to do with permissions or access tokens?

Comment: yes check the permissions you are setting on the 'get access token' button. you'll need to ask for additional friends permission like friends_birthday